# NExtJS getStaticProps() call every time

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have created nodejs server for nextjs app

```
onst app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
            const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
            await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
            res.statusCode = 500
            res.end('internal server error')
        }
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
});
```

And create build for next app and run start:server
**package.json**

```
"build": "next build",
"start:server": "SET NODE_ENV=production && node server.js"
```

Problem :
I have page with getStaticProps but when I reload page I have different content / Why ? I have create build and call getStaticProps

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const userRequest =
    await fetch('https://catfact.ninja/fact');
  const userData = await userRequest.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data: userData
    }
  };
}

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>
          Welcome 
        </h1>
       random  info {data.fact}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: is this problem in development or production? because [`getStaticProps` runs on every request in development](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#runs-on-every-request-in-development)

Comment: run nodejs server is not guarantee that is NODE_ENV=production  ? I  SET NODE_ENV=production

Comment: Either let @mocherfaoui add an answer or post one yourself below. Do not edit the solution into your question.